# How do I split a txt file by html tags or regex in order to save it as separate txt files in R?

Tags: html, r, strsplit

I have the output of a LexisNexis batch download of news articles in both html and txt format. The file itself contains the headers, metadata, and body of several different news articles that I need to systematically separate and save as independent txt files. The head of the txt version looks like:

```
> head(textz, 100)
[1] "ï»¿"                                                                              
[2] "                               1 of 103 DOCUMENTS"                                
[3] ""                                                                                 
[4] ""                                                                                 

[5] "                                Foreign Affairs"                                  

[6] ""                                                                                 
[7] "                              May 2013 - June 2013"                               
[8] ""                                                                                 
[9] "Why the U.S. Army Needs Armor Subtitle: The Case for a Balanced Force"            
[10] ""                                                                                 

[11] "BYLINE: Chris McKinney, Mark Elfendahl, and H. R. McMaster Authors BIOS: CHRIS"   
[12] "MCKINNEY is a Lieutenant Colonel in the U.S. Army and an adviser to the Saudi"    
[13] "Arabian National Guard. MARK ELFENDAHL is a Colonel in the U.S. Army and a"       
[14] "student at the Joint Advanced Warfighting School in Norfolk, Virginia. H. R."     
[15] "MCMASTER is a Major General in the U.S. Army and Commander of the Maneuver"       
[16] "Center of Excellence at Fort Benning, Georgia."                                   

[17] ""                                                                                 

[18] "SECTION: Vol. 92 No. 4 PAGE: 129"                                                 

[19] ""                                                                                 

[20] "LENGTH: 2856 words"                                                               

[21] ""                                                                                 

[22] ""                                                                                 

[23] "Ever since World War II, the United States has depended on armored forces --"     
[24] "forces equipped with tanks and other protected vehicles -- to wage its wars."
....
....
```

A snapshot of the html version looks like this:

```
<DOC NUMBER=103>
<DOCFULL> -->
<br><div class="c0">
<p class="c1"><span class="c2">103 of 103 DOCUMENTS</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c0">
<br><p class="c1"><span class="c2">The New York Times</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c3">
<p class="c1"><span class="c4">July</span>
<span class="c2"> 26, 2011 Tuesday</span>
<span class="c2">Â </span>
<span class="c2">Â <br>Late Edition - Final</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c5">
<p class="c6"><span class="c7">A Step Toward Trust With China</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c5">
<p class="c6"><span class="c8">BYLINE: </span><span class="c2">By MIKE MULLEN. </span></p>
<p class="c9"><span class="c2">Mike Mullen, a </span>
<span class="c4">Navy admiral,</span><span class="c2"> is the chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff.
</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c5">
<p class="c6"><span class="c8">SECTION: </span>
<span class="c2">Section A; Column 0; Editorial Desk; OP-ED CONTRIBUTOR; Pg. 23</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c5">
<p class="c6"><span class="c8">LENGTH: </span>
<span class="c2">794 words</span></p>
</div>
<br><div class="c5">
<p class="c9"><span class="c2">Washington</span></p>
<p class="c9"><span class="c2">THE military relationship between the United States and China is one of the world's most important. And yet, clouded by some misunderstanding and suspicion, it remains among the most challenging. There are issues on which we disagree and are tempted to confront each other. But there are crucial areas where our interests coincide, on which we must work together.
</span></p>
```

The unique documents are separated by the "[0-9] of [0-9] DOCUMENTS" lines in each, but between the grep family and strsplit I have been unable to find a way to split the txt (or html) file in R in a way that cleanly separates the component articles and allows me to save them as independent txt files. A thorough search of other questions threads was either unhelpful or required use of Python. Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the txt version, assuming text is in `doc_text`, and write each to a sequentially named files .txt, file2.txt etc.

lapply for file writing adapted from @P Lapointe

```
texts <- unlist(strsplit(doc_text, "\\s+\\d+\\sof\\s\\d+\\sDOCUMENTS") )
texts <- texts[-1]  # drop the first empty split

lapply (1:length(texts), function(i){ write(texts[i], paste0("file", i, ".txt"))})
```

Comment: The unlisted `texts` object has length equal to the number of lines in the text, rather than the number of documents. The `lapply` function then creates over 12,000 txt files, one for each line.

Comment: @M.Robinson Do you want one file per document or one file per html element?  I deleted my answer because it was downvoted. My answer had one "document" per file.

Comment: @P Lapointe Apologies; yes I did mean one file per document not per html element. But the lapply sequence you articulated for generating the txt files was very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Credit for the file writing belongs with @P Lapointe - I adapted from there.

Comment: @M.Robinson, my test string was assigned inline so it was a single string - not a vector of lines. Fora vector of lines,  add something like `doc_text  <- paste(textz, collapse = "\\n")` before the split.

Comment: Splendid! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

library `rvest` makes it easy parse html. Your documents are not quite consistent with the `<DOCFULL>` and `<DOC NUMBER >` headers. The answer below uses your provided document extended to show the next document (104). You can use the lapply structure to do other things like write a text file per article. Note the css selector in html_nodes. There doesn't seem to be much structure in the html, but if you find some patterns you could target bits of each article with selectors.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

articles  <- str_replace_all(doc, "\\n", " ") %>%    # remove new line to simplify
  str_replace_all("<DOCFULL>\\s+\\-\\->", " " ) %>%  # remove redundant header
  strsplit("<DOC NUMBER=\\d+>") %>%                  # split on DOC NUMBER header
  unlist()                                           # to a vector

# drop the first empty result form the split
articles <- articles[-1]

# use lapply to travers all articles. 
c2_texts <- lapply(articles, function (article) {
  article %>% 
    read_html() %>%           # character input parsed as html
    html_nodes(css=".c2") %>% # find nodes with CSS selector, ex: c2
    html_text() })            # extract text from within the node

c2_texts
# [[1]]
# [1] "103 of 103 DOCUMENTS"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# [2] "The New York Times"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
# [3] " 26, 2011 Tuesday"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
# [4] "Â "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
# [5] "Â Late Edition - Final"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# [6] "By MIKE MULLEN. "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
# [7] "Mike Mullen, a "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
# [8] " is the chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff.     "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# [9] "Section A; Column 0; Editorial Desk; OP-ED CONTRIBUTOR; Pg. 23"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
# [10] "794 words"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# [11] "Washington"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
# [12] "THE military relationship between the United States and China is one of the worlds most important. And yet, clouded by some misunderstanding and suspicion, it remains among the most challenging. There are issues on which we disagree and are tempted to confront each other. But there are crucial areas where our interests coincide, on which we must work together.     "
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "104 of 104 DOCUMENTS" "The Added Item"
```

Comment: This is almost right on target; once the lapply sequence has found the `c2` class object for determining where to split the text, what is the best systematic way to strip remaining header information while keeping the body intact? Regardless, thanks for the assist.